# Can't install nltk, due to errno 10060

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, anaconda, nltk

I have been trying to install nltk but every time i try to do so, i got the same error:

> Errno 10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>       properly respond after a period of time [closed]

My python interpreter runs on Anaconda Background, that is installed on Anaconda
and i have been running the command `nltk.download()` in the jupyter-notebook but the same error comes up every time.

I tried by disabling the proxies and disabling the web security as well and by running the internet connection by my phone data and wifi both.

This is the window i get:

[image: x]

Comment: try: `nltk.download('popular')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like NTLK does not get an answer from the download URL (I get this error when I have, for example, a typo in a URL).

The documentation indicates to launch the command from an administrator session. Is this your case?
You may have to run jupyter in administrator mode.

You can try, as indicated in the documentation, to launch the command through a proxy (there are some free, do a little research) :

```
>>> nltk.set_proxy('http://proxy.example.com:3128', ('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'))
>>> nltk.download()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is recently due to Wifi Issue. Wifi works fine but, `nltk` is not downloaded.

Please see this question:

[WinError 10060 Connection Timeout Error When Downloading 'punkt' in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77468918/winerror-10060-connection-timeout-error-when-downloading-punkt-in-nltk/77469069#77469069)

> It seems to be that on some networks, I've been told "Jio" is one of them, raw.githubusercontent.com is not accessible, e.g.: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.xml

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1981#issuecomment-1804689730

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3104