# WinError 10060 Connection Timeout Error When Downloading 'punkt' in NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I'm experiencing an issue with the NLTK library in Python, specifically when trying to download the 'punkt' tokenizer models. Here's the error message I receive:

**Context:**
I'm attempting to download the `punkt` package using the following code:

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

Troubleshooting Steps I've Taken:

Checked my internet connection, which seems to be working fine.
Temporarily disabled firewall and antivirus software, but the issue persists.
Attempted to use a different internet connection (e.g., mobile hotspot), but faced the same error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very strange error :

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1981#issuecomment-1804689730

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3104

> It seems to be that on some networks, I've been told "Jio" is one of them, raw.githubusercontent.com is not accessible, e.g.: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
import nltk
import os

nltk.download('punkt', download_dir=os.getcwd(), quiet=True)
```

download_dir=os.getcwd(): This specifies the download directory for the nltk resource. In this case, it's set to the current working directory (os.getcwd()). This means the 'punkt' resource will be downloaded to the same directory where your Python script or Jupyter notebook is located.

quiet=True: This parameter suppresses output during the download process, making it quieter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).